# Why does this tooltip fall off the screen on narrower screen sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/htmltooltip.js")">        </script>
```

from here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/htmltooltip.shtml

```
<i rel="htmltooltip">...tooltip link...</i>
<div class="htmltooltip">
    tooltip content
</div>
```

The style is injected in the Layout page.  When you re-size the browser window and hover over the tooltip it is cut-off on the right side.

```
    <style type="text/css">
    div.htmltooltip {
    position: absolute; /*leave this and next 3 values alone*/
    z-index: 1000;
    left: -1000px;
    top: -1000px;
    background: #ffff99;
    border: 2px;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 750px;
 }
</style>
```

I need the tooltip to stay in the middle of the browser window on any screen size.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please reproduce your problem in a fiddle ?

Comment: [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/unpctrbj/)

Comment: It is no longer falling off the screen, but new problem.  The line that triggers the tooltip on hover extends past the text.  The whole empty line will trigger the tooltip, not just hovering over the text.  How can I fix it so that hovering over only the text will trigger the tooltip?